# Django include statement is behaving odd

Tags: django, django-templates

The below code was working fine but recently it stated behaving odd on server.

views.py

```
context['data'] = [{'personal_email': 'personal_email@gmail.com', 'office_email': 'office_email@gmail.com'}]
```

Template

```
{% for i in  data %}
{{ i.personal_email }}
{{ i.office_email }}
{% include 'sample.html' with email=i.personal_email %}
{% include 'sample.html' with email=i.office_email %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am unable to get office_email in sample.html file

Comment: Try doing `i["office_email"]` and `i["personal_email"]` instead of `i.personal_email` or `i.office_email`

Comment: But my code is working fine with `personal_email` not with `office_email`

Comment: Nvm I am stupid. I did not know that template language does not use `variable["key"]` format for dictionaries.

Comment: You are calling the same template with the same variable name,  `email`. Change your variables to be distinct from each other.

Comment: Try renaming office email to email1

Comment: where is the error log?

Comment: Thanks Everyone, there was issue with `sample.html`. it was silently failing but not giving error on front end.